# Is there a live view pattern tile designer?

Tags: patterns

I seem to know how to make a tile-able/repeat pattern in Photoshop easily enough, but I'm wondering if there are any great tools available specifically for pattern tile design. It would be a great feature to be able to see how the pattern tiles as I edit it.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be the answer you were looking for, but it might be useful anyway.

Any search for *tile background generator* will give you more alternatives than you can shake a stick at.

You are not telling us what use you want; is this CSS pattern? General graphics? So here are a list of just a few *online* tools.

**http://bgpatterns.com/**

**http://www.patternify.com/**

**http://www.daltile.com/inspired/tools/mosaic-pattern-designer**

**http://singlefunction.com/15-online-background-generators/**

If what you are looking for is a plugin for photoshop, I am sure someone else will come along shortly with suggestions.

Comment: That's a great list. I guess I had the wrong search params. What would be the difference between a CSS pattern and "General graphics"? I don't need something to write CSS.
Patternify has the pattern features I want, but obviously comes up short in the raster editor dept. :D

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean; did you try downloading a png?